# Why B-tree block or SSTable file implementations keep headers/indexes at the end of file/block?

Tags: leveldb

Why this tendency (of keeping the "control structure" and the end of file/block) exists?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question about the SSTable format rather than about Bigtable.

See https://www.quora.com/Why-do-HFile-and-SSTable-store-their-indexes-at-the-end-of-the-file.

It's to avoid having to seek again when writing out the index - you can build up the index in memory as you write out the file and then write the index at the end.

The index may have offsets and you may not know its correct size until you are at the end.